# Cloud Tasks masks Bearer Token (To a Public Cloud Run)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I have a public Cloud Run, authenticated by JWT Token. Working 100%.
The logic inside the Cloud Run to decode the token is in python:

```
def decode_jwt(token: str) -> dict:
    try:
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(
            token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=[JWT_ALGORITHM])
        return decoded_token if decoded_token["expires"] >= time.time() else None
    except Exception as e:
        raise InvalidTokenError
```

The Cloud Run is publicly available using a custom domain.

Now, I want to do some requests to the Cloud Run, using Cloud Tasks (each request have different parameters, created previously by a Cloud Functions).
In the Cloud Tasks, I create each task with a "Bearer {token}" parameter

Cloud Task Headers Code:

```
task["http_request"]["headers"] = \
                {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
                 "Accept": "application/json"}
```

**First situation:**

When I create the task without the "oidc_token" parameter in the http_request creation.
Cloud Run returns "403 Forbidden", and never reach the decode_jwt function inside cloud run.
Cloud Task http_request Code:

```
task = {
        "http_request": {  
            "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
            "url": url,  
          }
       }
```

**Second situation:**
I add an "oidc_token".

```
task = {
        "http_request": {  
            "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
            "url": url,  
            "oidc_token": {
                "service_account_email": "service-task@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
           }
       }
```

Now, the request reach the Cloud Run **decode_jwt** function, and the log in Cloud Run returns "InvalidTokenError".
Extra: I added a logging.info to expose the token received in Cloud Run, and is not the token I passed in the Cloud Task Creation.

Comment: There are a lot of comments in the answer below which indicates a question lacking details to create a solid answer. Please edit your question to clearly show what you are trying to do and the problem/error. All tokens are signed by Google created private keys (there is one exception but that does not apply to Cloud Tasks). There are Google managed and user managed private keys for each service account. It should not matter to your application which one unless you are trying to verify the token signature. Include your logic that determines **invalid token**.

Comment: Thanks John, updated the question. Let me know if Im missing info.

Comment: My guess is that your **jwt.decode()** logic is broken. 1) What are **JWT_SECRET** and **JWT_ALGORITHM**? I am assuming that you are looking up the public key and passing that value. There is only one algorithm used **RS256**. To look up the public key, you must first extract the OIDC header **kid**. I do not see that logic in your question.

Comment: Note: **jwt.decode** throws an exception. The exception class will tell you what failed. Example: **jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError** or **jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError**.

Comment: Actually the Cloud Run app is working with regular requests, and cURL... I have about 15 different users (each one with a different token) using it everyday.. JWT_ALGORITHM I pick from an ENV variable. "HS256" currently. JWT_SECRET is the code I use to encode and create the token, I have differents secrets (For Dev and Prod Environments)

---- Yes, the exception is :
"jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed"
because is not the token I passed. Is the GCP created token. GCP Replaces my "Authorization": "Bearer {token}" using the GCP token.

Comment: The Google OAuth/OIDC algorithm is RS256 and not HS256. Cloud Tasks does not use your tokens for authorization to Cloud Run. Unless there are details missing in your question, you misunderstand how Cloud Tasks and Cloud Run implement authorization.

Comment: Note: you modified your comment while I was replying.

Comment: Exactly that John, I want to use my tokens. GCP don´t let me do that.

Comment: My only suggestion is to use a custom HTTP header.

Comment: Or add support for Google signed OIDC tokens.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info on the IAP John . Now I will look to a way to pass it as a custom header like you said, or passing in the payload maybe. Thanks, I think we can close this now. If you add that IAP comment as an answer, I can upvote and close this, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Summary:

1. you have a public (allUsers) Cloud Run service.
2. you have created your own authorization mechanism (HS256 - HMAC with SHA-256).
3. you want to assign a custom token for the HTTP Authorization Bearer value.
4. Cloud Run authorization is managed by IAP.

Authorization for the Cloud Run service is managed by the Identity Aware Proxy (IAP). If you add an HTTP Authorization Bearer token, IAP will verify that token. That step fails for your custom token which results in an HTTP 403 Forbidden error.

Cloud Tasks supports two types of HTTP Authorization Bearer tokens. OAuth Access tokens and OIDC Identity tokens. You cannot use your own token value to replace the supported types.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Enhance your code to support Google signed OIDC Identity Tokens.
2. Use a custom HTTP header that supports your custom token format.

**Note:** I do not recommend using HS256. HS256 is a symmetric algorithm which means the secret must be known to both sides in order to validate the payload. RS256 is an asymmetric algorithm which uses private/public key pairs. To verify only requires the public key. This is one of the strong design features of Google's use of private keys for service accounts and identities. If you switch to Google's method, all of the hard work is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specificy the audience of your Cloud Run service, like that

```
task = {
        "http_request": {  # Specify the type of request.
            "http_method": tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
            "url": url,  # The full url path that the task will be sent to.
            "oidc_token": {
                "service_account_email": "service-task@xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                "audience": base url of Cloud Run, no /sub/path
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried now adding:
1. the private URL in the audience 
2. the private URL  without the "http://"
3. the public URL in the audience 
4. the public URL  without the "http://"

Got the same error, invalid token.

Comment: There is no "private URL" with Cloud Run, only public with the pattern `https://<serviceName>-<hash>-<region code>.run.app`. This one must be added to the audience. So, another question: is the service account in the same project as Cloud Task queue?

Comment: I tried that url *.run.app (I tested also with the custom domain we use)
The Cloud Task and Cloud Run are in the same project/region

Comment: If you remove the security on your Cloud Run service, does it work? Do you have more details in the logs? What is the ingress configuration of the Cloud Run service? Did you change it?

Comment: The problem is I cant remove the JWT authentication, the token have an ID used inside the logic in the Cloud Run..

The log in the Cloud Run indicates that it received a JWT token, but it was a "gcp created" token, from the Cloud Tasks.. Raising an exception in the Application (Invalid Token).

I am testing passing a hard coded token in the Header of the Task, but GCP replace my token with another one.

Also, in the Cloud Run Permissions -> allUsers = Cloud Run Invoker

Comment: Hmmm, wait. Just to clarify: do you successfully invoke the Cloud Run service? If so, from where come the 403 error? From your own code logic? If so, can you detail what do you want to provide to your service not to fail?

Comment: Exactly, I succesfully invoked the Cloud Run...

The logs in the Cloud Run indicates "POST 500 726 B 4 ms Google-Cloud-Tasks https://xxxxxxx". And before that, the traceback indicates "Invalid Token"

Comment: Ok, 500 means an internal error in your process. As far as understand, you expect to get the requester identity in the Authorization header, but you get the Google Cloud service account identity token instead. Your process fail because the identity is not known. Can you change in the Cloud Run code the header in which you are searching for the user identity token?

Comment: I will test that now, because John mentioned GCP uses IAP and I cant use my custom tokens.

Comment: No problem. John is an awesome engineer and a mentor for me in my path to become a GCP expert!